# How to ensure that autofs and nfs are ready before another service?

Tags: dependencies, upstart, services, init.d

Under Ubuntu 14.04, I have developed a program in C++ that writes to an NFSv4 volume mounted by autofs.

The program works fine when my machine has already "warmed up".

However, it crashes when it's started as a service at boot time - I wrote a script for it under /etc/init.d and enabled it via `update-rc.d`.

Upon examining the core dump, I see that it failed to create a file under the NFSv4 volume. In fact, I can reproduce the problem even in the terminal, if I launch the program quickly enough right after reboot.

How can I ensure that autofs and nfs are ready before my service starts?

**I have already added `$network` and `autofs` to the `Required-Start` clause of my init script, but it looks like that's not enough. It also has nothing to do with hostname resolution because the IP address of the NFS server is specified in the autofs rule.**

Comment: tryy adding `$remote_fs` as a required-start.

Comment: I think the problem is that autofs is starting as an upstart job where you start your service with and SysV initscript. Creating direct dependencies between the two worlds is nearly impossible and you could e.g. start all SysV scripts after autofs. Better would be to write an upstart job for your service where you can create a direct dependency.

Comment: @meuh $remote_fs is already among Required-Start explicitly (it's also implied by autofs).

Comment: @Thomas I just double-checked and autofs is not managed by Upstart, according to `service --status-all`. It's a SysV init script.

Comment: Is it enabled? By default `autofs` is started with `upstart` because there is a `/etc/init/autofs.conf` file as well. If you start with SysV you can just add the name of your service to the `Required-Start` section, then disable and reenable your service.

Comment: @Thomas Ok. Ubuntu is so confusing. I thought a `[+]` in `service --status-all` means it's a SysV-style service.
Is there a way this question can be moved to AskUbuntu? I think this is mostly a Ubuntu/Upstart oddity at this point.

Comment: This also begs another question: if autofs is actually managed by Upstart, how did `update-rc.d` even manage to install symlinks for my service to `/etc/rc*.d/`? Shouldn't it either install symlinks for the autofs init script as well, or just fail? `update-rc.d` did neither. This seems really broken.

Comment: You might want to rethink this considerably. Ubuntu has dropped upstart so you might want to consider switching to systemd instead. Even if you manage to get it to work or 14.04, it won't work on 16.04, the current LTS release.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for migrating the question.

I'm not worried about systemd, at least not yet, because the program's target deployment environment is specifically Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You're welcome. As for 14.04, I guess that makes sense, it will be supported until [April 1019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) after all.